discord.py-PermissionOverwrite, from Digiwind's video
I'm trying to make a ticketing bot and I've got an exception using PermissionOverwrite function which I don't know how to resolve:
The Stack Trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tserp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
await item.callback(interaction)

File "d:\ticket bot DOK\main.py", line 48, in Dep_Button
interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_massages=True, attach_files=True, embed_links=True),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\tserp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\discord\permissions.py",
line 828, in __init__
raise ValueError(f'no permission called {key}.')


The code involved:
47  interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
48  interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_massages=True, attach_files=True, embed_links=True),
49  interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_massages=True, read_massage_history=True)

The code is from Digiwind video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pku9WO1oMXg)
I expected the bot to change the channel permissions. What am I missing?

Copying the full error message is better than a screenshot.

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

There is a send_massages=True permission enabling in your code (line 48 and 49).
This permission key cannot be found because it should be messages with an 'e': send_messages=True.
Fixing this typo will get rid of your exception.

thx! i kind of found it myself 20 mins after that...
